# Crash : if the file name consists forward slash like "te/st.pdf"

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

If the file name consists forward slash like "te/st.pdf"

```
[data writeToFile:@"/Documents/te/st.pdf" atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil]
```

is there any solution rather than replacing the forward slash '/' with some other character.

Comment: The slash is the path separator and *not allowed* in a file name. `/Documents/te/st.pdf` stands for "st.pdf" in the directory "te" in the "/Documents" directory.

Comment: @MartinR yes I know it. But My requirement is I need to write a filename (which consists forward slash in it). So that why I'm looking for a solution.  In mac machine you can create a file name with forward slash / but the thing is when you try to copy the path of the file it replaces / with :

Comment: Yes, the Finder silently translates / to : and back. As I said, you cannot create a file "te/st.pdf" in the HFS (or any other Unix-like) file system, there is no way around it.

Answer (score 2):

For some odd reason you have to use `\:` So it would be

```
[data writeToFile:@"/Documents/te\:st.pdf" atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil]
```

It works but compiler complains about unknown escape sequence.
If you'll execute `ls -la` in folder where you create file with forward slash you'll see it is named `the:st.pdf`

Comment: I don't want to replace it with another characters. Is there any other solution for it

Comment: You don't need to change file name, only string passed to `writeToFile`. I don't think there are any other options because forward slash is a path separator so system can't know if you're using slash to indicate folder or it is a part of filename

Comment: `"\/"` is equal to `"/"`, that does not make any difference (only that it causes a compiler warning "Unknown escape sequence"). And the slash is not allowed as part of a filename.

Comment: @MartinR I know slash is not allowed in file paths. But when you observe in machine you can create file with name consists for forward slash.

Comment: I changed my answer to show the correct sequence. Sorry for the previous wrong one:)

Answer (score 0):

I did not get exactly why you are using forward slash in code as it indicates macos filepath. Well if you do not want to replace or escape than there is only one way just rename your file using below code.

```
 NSError * err = NULL;
 BOOL result = [[NSFileManger     
 defaultManger moveItemAtPath:@"/  
    Documents/te/st.pdf" toPath: @"/
  Documents/test.pdf"   error:&err];
 if(!result)
NSLog(@"Error: %@", err);
```

Comment: Actually I need to share the file through mail attachment. My client   doesn't to change the name of the file. You're solution is to move a file from one location to another location but I need to write a file at my local path

Comment: Yes correct but this will not move it will rename your file. But you can do one thing just rename it using above code then write it and then again rename to the same filename with forward slash. Can you try like this.

Comment: So that it will not crash and your filename with forward slash will be there.

Comment: in order move a file first I need to create the file. While  creating the file with the name is getting crashed

Comment: Ok so np you need to first create the file right? So why don't you create without forward slash name. Once you write then change the filename with including forward slash. What do you say??

Answer (score 0):

Even easier solution: Just change the character to `:`

You don't need to use the `\:` At least in my XCode 6.3.2 it works. So this WILL NOT produce the warning. Your code will just be:

```
[data writeToFile:@"/Documents/te:st.pdf" atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil]
```

And if you want to use a name with `:` [(colon)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colon_(punctuation)) is is also possible, but you will need to use this Unicode character => `꞉` [MODIFIER LETTER COLON (Unicode U+A789)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colon_(punctuation)#Letter)